# jQuery image swapping animation Firefox flickering

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, drag

So I made an image flipbook animation that reacts to mousedrag. It works fine in Safari & IE but not Firefox. As I drag the mouse around, the swapping images would flicker. I'm afraid somehow the `img` or `div` is being selected causing the flicker so I turned off any selectable attributes. I even turned of the dragging and just used x-mouse position. It still flickers. Is it a memory issue with rendering or my code? These are fairly large images like 800px x 500px.

```
(function($){
  $.fn.setframe = function(frame){

  return this.each(function(){
        var $image = $(this);
        function imageName(frame){
            return 'images/inx'+frame+'.png';
        }

       $image.attr('src', imageName(frame));

    });
};
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
   var dragDistance = 15;
   var originalX = null;
   var frame = 1;

   $('.cot').mousedown(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         originalX = e.pageX - frame * dragDistance;

         $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               frame = Math.floor( ((e.pageX - originalX) / dragDistance) % 35);
               if(frame > 0) {
                     $('img.inx').setframe(frame);
               } else {
                     $('img.inx').setframe(Math.abs(frame+ 35));
               }

         });

   });

   $(this).mouseup(function() {
         $(document).unbind('mousemove');
   });

 }

$('img').live('selectstart dragstart', function(evt){ evt.preventDefault(); return false; });
$('.cot').live('selectstart dragstart', function(evt){ evt.preventDefault(); return false; });
$('img').disableSelection();
$('.cot').disableSelection();


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid the way it is animating. Don't use image swapping for large image or you'll see image flickering on certain browsers. Instead I `hide()` and `show()` layers to `animate`.